# Jmeter and non internet apps

Tags: jmeter

Helow
Is it possible to use Jmeter to make a performance test on a mobile app which doesn´t connect to internet, such as calendar or calculator; an app that doesn´t use http protocol?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

JMeter acts on **protocol** level, it doesn't actually clicks links or buttons, it sends requests over variety of supported protocols (not limited to HTTP) and records response times.

If your application doesn't have a backend, i.e. it is completely standalone, you normally don't need to load test it as it won't have more than one user. The only thing you can do is to check resources impact like CPU or RAM usage, battery consumption, most long running code parts, etc. Check out the following materials:

- [Android Performance Profiling Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html)
- [iOS App Performance: Instruments & beyond](https://medium.com/@mandrigin/ios-app-performance-instruments-beyond-48fe7b7cdf2#.a0frape66)
- [Performance Profiling on Windows Phone 8.1 with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/04/03/performance-profiling-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio/)

For more detailed explanation of the concept of simulating multiple non-browser applications users check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Very kind of you. Thank you very much, Dmitri

Comment: I suggest using the tool "app tupe-up kit" for android devices. It alows test a separate app and show data abot the use of cpu, gpu, battery, incoming data, sent data, device´s temperature, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need internet connection in order to test like a local website, service or app. And yes, it is possible.

If your app is locally then the app will be available on a localhost port ( db, api, website). If you plan to test from the UI perspective a mobile or desktop app then you are using the wrong tool and  you should use other tools like Ranorex or Test Complete.

Comment: Then, how can I join the mobile and jmeter? setting the IP of the pc where Jmeter runs as proxy for the wifi connection of the mobile? I have already tried, but doesn´t work.

Comment: If your app is locally then the app will be available on a localhost port ( db, api, website). If you plan to test from the UI perspective a mobile app then you are using the wrong tool and  you should use other tools like Ranorex or Test Complete.